# How do I copy only files of a certain date range?

Tags: files

I wanted to copy files that were created within a week. I have a glut of hundreds of photos and I wanted to separate them into folders for each week to make them easier to manage. What terminal commands can I use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try or explore This Command...

```
find A -ctime -18 -ctime +1 -exec cp \{\} B/ \;
```

This command of for [2015-01-01 to 2015-01-08] dates but
You can modify your date respectively..

I haven't tried it on my machine .. but I guess it will work fine !